# Returning zero when no matching rows exist

Tags: sql

I have a table containing three columns: Age (bucket), Date of Registration & Numbers Registered. Currently, only rows exist where there are registration for that date and age bucket. There are currently 11 age buckets and 14 dates. Therefore I'd like the output to have 154 rows (11 x 14). The SQL Code I have is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Age INTO #AgesTable FROM #Output
SELECT DISTINCT DateRegistered INTO #DatesTable FROM #Output

SELECT
a.Age
, d.DateRegistered
, COALESCE(o.Registrations, 0) AS Registrations
FROM #Output o
FULL OUTER JOIN #AgesTable a ON o.Age = a.Age
FULL OUTER JOIN #DatesTable d on o.DateRegistered = d.DateRegistered
WHERE a.Age = '''80+'
```

.... or have I gone about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to cross join a & d then left join o.

```
;WITH CTE_AGE AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT Age 
  FROM #Output
)
, CTE_DATES AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT DateRegistered
  FROM #Output
)
SELECT a.Age, d.DateRegistered
, COALESCE(o.Registrations, 0) AS Registrations
FROM CTE_AGE a 
CROSS JOIN CTE_DATES d 
LEFT JOIN #Output o
  ON o.Age = a.Age
 AND o.DateRegistered = d.DateRegistered
WHERE a.Age LIKE '%80+'
```

Comment: Thanks for that LukStorms. I ran into a SQL error with the first half of your suggestion With CTE_Age AS ... but when I replaced that with the original two lines creating two distinct tables, the whole thing worked beautifully. Again, really appreciate the help and quick response.

Comment: Maybe because the WITH clause has this special requirement that the previous statement needs to be closed. Then putting a `;` before it fixes it.  `;WITH... `

Comment: Also, a CTE is like a template for a sub-query. It allows to re-use the same sub-query. But joining on sub-queries is basically the same. If a CTE is used only once, it's just syntatic sugar.